# “Couldn’t get size: 0x800000000000000e” has happened after boot menu for installing Ubuntu18.04 server on Intel Compute Stick

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 19.04

I have followed [this guide](https://jamesachambers.com/install-ubuntu-server-18-04-on-intel-compute-stick-guide/) for installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS to Intel Compute Stick.
However, the installer shows "Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e" and many messages, failed to start installing.

The photo of the errors [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Re0X.jpg).

I am sure I have written correct image which [downloaded from here](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) into the USB drive. I tried 19.04 right now. But "Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e" has shown again... How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded file?  Have you upgraded the stick's firmware to the latest version (40 for the STCK1A8LFC)? See https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28922/BIOS-Update-FCBYT10H-86A-?v=t  for the download.

Comment: I have upgraded the stick's firmware to the latest version which you mentioned.

Comment: I am sure I got right ISO. I used ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso. It seems if the installation failed, 14.04 is launched.

Comment: If you select the USB installer after the F10 at startup (needs to be typed at the Intel splash screen, but it only show for a second), what happens?  Does your USB installer boot on other machines? When F10 is typed in time, you should get a choice of the internal 14.04, the internal recovery option, and the USB.

Comment: If I select the USB installer after the F10 at startup, the grub menu is shown.
My USB installer can boot on other machines.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the ubuntu server 18.04.2 and made an installer USB with the ISO.  Your error at running the installer is present on my system too, but it's just a warning, nothing wrong really. The 14.04 reference is to the internal system on the stick, so that's OK.  The next few lines after your screen shot on my system are:

```
mount: Mounting /root/cdrom/casper/extras/modules.squashfs.generic on root/lib/modules failed: no such file or directory
Documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/
stopping bluetooth deamon
Starting Bridge file events into upstart
Starting bridge socket events into upstart
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

The normal desktop is present on tty7. The startup messages are on tty1, so try typing Alt F7 to get to the desktop.  I let the internal 14.04 upgrade to 16.04 but mostly run off systems installed to a microSD.